# Error converting to float in python that others don't seem get

Tags: python, exponential

Im trying to plot data from a text file and i keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/photonics/photon test n stuff/copying 7a from paper 2/wont work.py", line 15, in <module>
    T.append(float(lines[x].strip()))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9.17973518E'
```

Ive asked around and other people are telling me theyre not getting the error.

https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/python-converting-exponential-im-getting-error-r-2-545454py-line-18-tappend-float-lines-x--q34639464

https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/python-lists-reading-files-im-trying-make-list-1-r-t-use-first-500-values-r-t-different-le-q34610346

Heres my whole code.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
################################### making R list
f=open('R 77777.txt',"r")
lines=f.readlines()
R=[]
for x in range(500):
    R.append(float(lines[x].strip()))
f.close()
################################### making T list
f=open('T 77777.txt',"r")
lines=f.readlines()
T=[]
for x in range(500):
    T.append(float(lines[x].strip()))
f.close()
################################## each A = 1 - R[i] - T[i]
A=[]
for i in range(len(R)):
    A.append(1 - (R[i]) - (T[i]))
K=numpy.linspace(0,100,500)
#print(K)
plt.plot(K, A)
plt.title("K over A")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(K, R)
plt.title( " R = Y, K = x ")
plt.show()
```

Heres my data.

find T list at https://pastebin.com/y2Uby5eF

find R list at https://pastebin.com/nX2Y6TVH

Why am i getting this issue but not others?

Comment: please help, still no dice

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet:The string float is getting doesn't have any numbers after E so it's probably not viewing it as scientific notation.

Comment: no i searched 9.17973518E in my data. it is just the first piece of data in my T file in exponential form
but its like all the other 9.17973518E-2  it has a power

Comment: whats more annoying is the R list brings up no errors

Comment: I'm just going off of what the error says. When you get a Value Error it shows you the value that was being passed and it says '9.17973518E'. If you try and enter that into float() manually it fails but if you remove the E or add numbers after it, it works. Did you check to see if maybe that value appears twice and one is broken?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your data is in scientific notation.

The float() function in Python has some trouble with this type of input.

**In order for this to work properly, you need to preserve the suffix.**

```
x = "9.17973518E-02"

float(x)
```

Comment: im sorry, what do you mean by that? i need to float each x seperatley